# TeamCity Meta-Runner: Correctly resolve dependent parameters

Tags: teamcity

I'm trying to set up a TeamCity meta-runner that provides defaults for a lot of the parameters. Some parameters depend on each other by including them. Here is a (contrived) example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<meta-runner name="TestMetaRunner">
  <description>Test the MetaRunners</description>
  <settings>
    <parameters>
      <param name="testMetaRunner.Name" value="theName" />
      <param name="testMetaRunner.Value" value="theValue" />
      <param name="testMetaRunner.Arguments" value="-param %testMetaRunner.Name%=%testMetaRunner.Value%" />
    </parameters>
    <build-runners>
      <runner name="Do it" type="simpleRunner">
        <parameters>
          <param name="script.content" value="someCommand %testMetaRunner.Arguments%" />
          <param name="teamcity.step.mode" value="default" />
          <param name="use.custom.script" value="true" />
        </parameters>
      </runner>
    </build-runners>
    <requirements />
  </settings>
</meta-runner>
```

Normally, users of the meta runner would only specify the parameters `testMetaRunner.Name` and `testMetaRunner.Value`, but for the more complex usages, `testMetaRunner.Arguments` would need to be modified directly.

The problem is, that TeamCity seems unable to resolve parameters in parameter values, so the value passed to `script.content` still contains parameter names - clearly not what I intended to achieve.

What is the correct way to implement scenarios as above with meta runners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to create a dedicated meta runner for **each level of abstraction** and reuse the meta runner in the more specific meta runner **as just another build step**.

Applied to the example above, this leads to the following two meta runner specifications:

#### Generic meta runner that provides more configuration possibilities

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<meta-runner name="TestMetaRunnerGeneric">
  <description>Test the MetaRunners</description>
  <settings>
    <parameters>
      <param name="testMetaRunner.Arguments" spec="text validationMode='not_empty'" />
    </parameters>
    <build-runners>
      <runner name="Do it" type="simpleRunner">
        <parameters>
          <param name="script.content" value="someCommand %testMetaRunner.Arguments%" />
          <param name="teamcity.step.mode" value="default" />
          <param name="use.custom.script" value="true" />
        </parameters>
      </runner>
    </build-runners>
    <requirements />
  </settings>
</meta-runner>
```

#### Specific meta runner that applies some defaults and provides simpler configuration

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<meta-runner name="TestMetaRunnerSpecific">
  <description>Test the MetaRunners</description>
  <settings>
    <parameters>
      <param name="testMetaRunner.Name" value="theName" />
      <param name="testMetaRunner.Value" value="theValue" />
    </parameters>
    <build-runners>
      <runner name="Call other meta runner" type="TestMetaRunnerGeneric">
        <parameters>
          <param name="testMetaRunner.Arguments" value="-param %testMetaRunner.Name%=%testMetaRunner.Value%" />
        </parameters>
      </runner>
    </build-runners>
    <requirements />
  </settings>
</meta-runner>
```